# Python - Pandas - Key Error during dropna call for specific subsets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal: I wish to drop rows who have NaN in specific columns. I will allow NaN to exist on some columns but not others. 
English Example: If value of 'detail_age' in a row is NaN, I want to remove that row.

Here is a view of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('allDeaths.csv', index_col=0, nrows=3, engine='python')
print(df.shape)
print(list(df))
```

Which outputs:

```
(3,15)
['education_1989_revision', 'education_2003_revision', 
'education_reporting_flag', 'sex', 'detail_age', 'marital_status', 
'current_data_year', 'injury_at_work', 'manner_of_death', 'activity_code', 
'place_of_injury_for_causes_w00_y34_except_y06_and_y07_', '358_cause_recode', 
'113_cause_recode', '39_cause_recode', 'race']
```

When I attempt to remove rows who's columns value is NaN with the following:

```
df.dropna(subset=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14], axis=1, inplace=True, how='any')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 10, in <module>
    df.dropna(subset=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14], axis=1, inplace=True, how='any')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3052, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
KeyError: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Which is weird because this works:

```
df.dropna(subset=[2], axis=1, inplace=True, how='any')
```

But not this:

```
df.dropna(subset=[5], axis=1, inplace=True, how='any')
```

So there must be something wrong with certain columns or the values in those columns. Here is a peek at my data with df.head(3):

[image: As image because formatting is annoying]

Comment: your DF has only 3 rows (`shape: (3,15)`), so there is nothing to drop ;-)

Comment: `df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True, how='any')` should be enough.

Comment: @MaxU , does it throw that error when there is no rows to drop? The data is actually 27 million rows but i decided to keep it short for posting.

Comment: @Ryan, do you want to drop rows or columns?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , I wish to drop rows that have NaN in specific columns. I want to still have NaN in the education columns but not in other columns. I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: @MaxU I want to drop rows who's values in specific columns are NaN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [360]: df
Out[360]:
      A     B     C   D
0   1.0   2.0   NaN   4
1   5.0   NaN   7.0   8
2   NaN  10.0  11.0  12
3  13.0  14.0  15.0  16

In [362]: df = df.dropna(subset=df.columns[[1,2]], how='any')

In [363]: df
Out[363]:
      A     B     C   D
2   NaN  10.0  11.0  12
3  13.0  14.0  15.0  16
```

PS of course you can specify column names instead:

```
In [370]: df.dropna(subset=['B','C'], how='any')
Out[370]:
      A     B     C   D
2   NaN  10.0  11.0  12
3  13.0  14.0  15.0  16
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you. What is the reason why I have to obtain the columns like that? I must be misunderstanding either subset or how the dataframe is stored

Comment: @Ryan, `subset` expects labels - either column names or index values (depending on spcified axis)