# dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thresh'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a list of column names & want to drop the rows that have more than 1 `NaN` values but this error occurs: `dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thresh'`.
My pandas is updated, the version is 1.1.5
Previously I've [done a little data cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565666/dealing-with-numeric-range-like-data-in-a-dataframe), think it caused my df rows to become **str**, but I converted them to `np.nan`...

**My Whole Code:**

```py
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

""" # DataClean
for col in col_list:
  df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col]
    .str.replace('[^0-9\- ]', '')
    .str.split(' - ')
    .explode()
).mean(level=0)
"""

df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)

for col in col_list:
   df[col] = df[col].dropna(thresh=1, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `dropna(thresh=1, axis=0)` it will drop rows that have just `nan` values, for your purpose, you can do the following:

```
df.dropna(subset=col_list, how='any', axis=0)
```

Comment: thanks but it gives me `KeyError` on column names, though tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361424/python-pandas-key-error-during-dropna-call-for-specific-subsets), didn't work dunno why..

Comment: It would be great if you could put a sample data, so we could reproduce the code and check how it works on our system.

Comment: I edited my answer, would you please try it now to see if it works?

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy learning and coding!

Comment: If you wanted this to be a threshold of 4 vs 1, what would you do? Because I am getting the exact same error but want to remove with a threshold higher than 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 1]
```

which will do similar work!

Comment: this deleted all `NaN` on all columns, want to drop NaN of just three specific columns.